# MySQL insert command using prepared statement and placeholders is not working

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I built a MySql database and a C# Windows GUI form to with textbox fields and a timedate picker to populate a table named 'job' in my database.

I have read a few posts on this site about the importance of using prepared statements to prevent sql injection attacks and I tried to use this security feature in my code.
However it is not working. I am a web designer but very new to programming. I tried different code variations at the insert command still won't work. The samples I have found on this form involve using prepared statements with PHP, which is not what I am using.

I get the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual or your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jobTitle, this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated')' at line 1

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

This is the MySQL statement for the table.

CREATE TABLE job (

```
job_code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
    job_last_update DATE NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (job_code)
```

)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

And this is my C# for the event handler that will save the data entry from the windows form to the database.

private void btnSaveJobsTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        String myConnection = @"server=localhost; database=beautyshopdb; username=$$$$; password=$$$$$$";
        MySqlConnection Connect = null;
        try
        {
            Connect = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            Connect.Open(); //open the connection
            //This is the mysql command that we will query into the db.
            //It uses Prepared statements and the Placeholder is @name.
            //Using prepared statements is faster and secure.
            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO beautyshopdb(job) VALUES(@jobCode, @)jobTitle, @lastUpdated)";
            MySqlCommand cmdInsertJobsToDataBase = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, Connect);
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Prepare();
            //we will bound a value to the placeholder
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobCode", "this.txtEnterJobCode.Text");
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobTitle", "this.txtEnterJobTitle.Text");
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastUpdated", "this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated");
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the mysql command
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connect != null)
            {
                Connect.Close(); //close the connection
            }
        }
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Bill!! I looked further into the code and fix the glitches you noticed. I also found a couple other syntax errors and fixed those. The INSERT command now works perfectly with both prepared statements and placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C# developer, but this doesn't look right, I think you have an extra parenthesis before `jobTitle`:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO beautyshopdb(job) VALUES(@jobCode, @)jobTitle, @lastUpdated)";
```

Also you seem to be putting variable references inside quotes as if they are string constants. I would expect these to require no quotes.

```
cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobCode", "this.txtEnterJobCode.Text");
```

Should be:

```
cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobCode", this.txtEnterJobCode.Text);
```